# How to animate a search field expanding from right to left in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, animation

What I'm trying to reach is similar to what is implemented on youTube app on iPad. The search field is expanding in animation from right to left. I'm trying to do so and i'm getting very strange and not smooth animation, Although left to right is working perfect.

|<-------------------------------|Search Field|

It seems that the origin value is changed first and than the width changed , un like the left-right expanding animation that the origin stays the same.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using frames or autolayout?

Comment: First set the anchor point of search filed & fix it on right. Then scale the image size 0 to your requirement size.

Answer (score -1):

You can use animation just put Search field in dynamically in view and put below code.

```
[UIView beginAnimations : @"Display notif" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.30];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:FALSE];

CGRect frGnrVw = generalView.frame; 
CGRect frTblNote =  tblNotes.frame;
frGnrVw.size.height = 0.0;
frGnrVw.size.height += 78.0;
generalView.frame = frGnrVw;


[UIView commitAnimations];
```

In above code general view is my view which has hight 0 and when some action called at that time view height increase and and we will see that view  expanding down in that i can not change view's x and y position But in your case first hide your view and when search action calls set hidden NO of your view and in my code i increase height so you can increase your width and also change it's x position means (decrese) i.e you increase width 320 than you decrese it x position to 320 .

just try it it will work.

you can also put it statically in your story board or in nib just set its width =0 and x= 320.

you have to do like below.

```
[UIView beginAnimations : @"Display notif" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.30]; // set duration of animation in seconds.
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:FALSE];
CGRect frGnrVw = generalView.frame;  //get frame of view.
frGnrVw.size.width = 0.0;
frGnrVw.size.width += 320.0;//increase width.
frGnrVw.origin.x -=320.0; // decrese position.
generalView.frame = frGnrVw; //set new frame to view.

[UIView commitAnimations]; // this will require.
```

you just put your view with search field at the position x=320 ,y = as your requirement ,width = 0 and height = as your requirement.

try it it will work.

Also you can hide like same in reverse order.
means increase its x position and decrease its width with above code.
If my answer helps than please vote up my answer.